# Hex literal syntax for literals in webassembly (wast)

Tags: webassembly

Webassembly: I cannot find a reference for this syntax `(f32.const -0x0p+0)`. What number / bit pattern does it represent? It is from a test file for the reference interpreter:

https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/f32.wast#L19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s hexadecimal floating-point as supported by C and [more recently C++](http://wg21.link/p0245).

The significand is given in hexadecimal, and the exponent is given in decimal and interpreted with respect to base 2. It can exactly represent all floating-point numbers except NaNs.

The text format adopted this in [this issue](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/292).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

It is hexadecimal float notation, as inspired by C and other languages.

The respective specification can be found [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/values.html#floating-point).